# Error after importing UFPS latest in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, error-handling, textures, texture2d

I just downloaded UFPS asset in unity but after importing i get some errors. I cant find a way online on how to fix that.

Unity Version: 2018

Errors:

> Assets/UFPS/Base/Scripts/Gameplay/Player/Local/vp_LocalPlayer.cs(62,46): error CS1540: Cannot access protected member `UnityEngine.Texture.Texture()' via a qualifier of type`UnityEngine.Texture'. The qualifier must be of type `vp_LocalPlayer' or derived from it

:

> Assets/UFPS/Base/Scripts/Gameplay/Player/Local/vp_LocalPlayer.cs(62,46): error CS0122: `UnityEngine.Texture.Texture()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Line with error:

```
static Texture m_InvisibleTexture = new Texture();
```

Comment: Have you tried posting a comment on that asset to see if they are aware of the issue?  Can you also post the version of Unity you are using?

Comment: One last thing, did you also try running the updater that comes with that asset?

Comment: The updater didn't work but it seems that the project was not updated to work with unity 2018 beta so I had to use unity 2017.

Comment: So it works with 2017?  Also, what is that texture being used for?  if you know I can probably give you a work around for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line with

```
private static Texture m_InvisibleTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
```

You'll also run into this error:

> Assets/UFPS/Base/Scripts/Gameplay/Editor/vp_FootstepManagerEditor.cs(228,25):
>   error CS0143: The class `UnityEngine.AudioClip' has no constructors
>   defined

Here's a link to a fix and more about the problems you'll encounter:

http://www.opsive.com/assets/UFPS/forum/index.php?p=/discussion/3979/2018-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

static Texture m_InvisibleTexture = new Texture(); // ERROR
static Texture m_InvisibleTexture = null; // NO ERROR